# How to access $http response from the finally block

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-http

I have an `$http` request that is handled by a success and error function, and there is something I would like to do with the response in both cases:

```
$http(params)
  .then(success, error);

var success = function(response) { 
  // do stuff
  foo(response);
}
var error = function(response) { 
  // do other stuff
  foo(response);
}
```

I'd prefer not to repeat code in both handlers, and I thought I might use `finally` to solve this problem but it seems the `finally` function doesn't receive any arguments.

Am I stuck calling `foo(response)` from both the `success` and the `error` function?  Or is there a better way?  (please say there is a better way...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is convert the failure into success:

```
$http(params)
  .then(success, error)
  .then(foo);

var success = function(response) { 
  // do stuff
  return response;
}
var error = function(response) { 
  // do other stuff
  return response;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`finally` callback is called with [no arguments](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.6/src/ng/q.js#L469). [The manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) reasonably explains this:

> finally(callback, notifyCallback) – allows you to observe either the
>   fulfillment or rejection of a promise, **but to do so without modifying
>   the final value**.

This behaviour complies with other promise implementations (particularly [`Q`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisefinallycallback), which was the inspiration for `$q`).

The pattern for result processing may be

```
$http(...)
.catch(function (err) {
  // condition err response
  return err;
})
.then(function (result) {
  // ...
});
```

This isn't the same as `finally`, because this chain results in fulfilled promise (unless the rejection took place in `then`), while `finally` doesn't affect chain state (unless the rejection took place in `finally`).

Comment: this part helped me: "finally doesn't affect chain state", thanks